# Hi everyone, I have Problem with using wp_die()

Tags: wp-admin, json

I have created a custom registration form in WordPress and everything works fine. 
The error handling and database operations also fine.

The only problem is that the JSON response I return is printed on all pages in WordPress including admin account, dashboard, pages, and all posts. I have looked for in it google, the only thing I got is to use wp_die() if I use this wp_die() at end of my functions.php files function I get a white page without issue resolved.

Can anyone know any solution for this? I have attached the screenshot of the WordPress dashboard.[image]

Comment: Can you please share your code. Without code, nobody can understand what was wrong that is triggering this. BTW, if anything is strictly for front end only, a conditional like `if (! is_admin() ) { // do something; }` could do the trick. BTW this is not a solution here.

Comment: Where is that in 'view source' in your browser? I'd guess you're actually generating it first, before the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Class to embed functions in function.php file. And also used namespace to call ajax requests. So no conflicts in displaying messages